# Trouble with bookmark-set in bookmark+ (emacs 24.5)

Tags: variables, emacs, bookmarks, lexical-scope

Emacs raises "funcall: Symbol's value as variable is void: choices" on bookmark-set.

After disabling bookmark+, bookmark-set started to work correctly.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Might you need to byte-recompile `bookmark+`, e.g. with `byte-recompile-file` or `byte-recompile-directory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any use of a variable named `choices` in the [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) code.

What is the most recent `Last-Updated` date you see in any of the Bookmark+ source-file headers?

I would suggest that you do this, if you haven't done it already:

1. Check whether you have something in `bmkp-after-set-hook`.  If so, try removing it to see whether that removes the error.
2. Download the latest Bookmark+ source files ([from Emacs Wiki or from MELPA](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#toc3)).
3. Delete any byte-compiled (i.e., `*.elc`) versions of the files that you might have.
4. Try again, to see if you get the same error.  If so, please report it to me by email: `M-x bmkp-send-bug-report`.
5. If not (no such error anymore):

   a. Load source file `bookmark+-mac.el`, which defines Lisp macros used by the other files.

   b. Byte-compile `bookmark+-mac.el`.

   c. Byte-compile the other files.  (An easy way to do this is to mark them in Dired and use `B`.)

   d. Restart Emacs and see whether you get the error again (you will be using the byte-compiled files this time).  If so, `M-x bmkp-send-bug-report`.

Sorry for your trouble. Let me know, and I'll get it fixed.  If you use `M-x bmkp-send-bug-report` then please try to provide a complete recipe to repro the problem, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).  Thx.

Comment: This error acquired only in case when ido-ubiquitous is enabled, and it relates on ido-completing-read+ function, where choices setted:

(setq choices
                  (append def
                          (nreverse (cl-set-difference choices def)))
                  def (car def))

Comment: OK. Sorry, but I don't understand everything that you are saying. Do you think that there is a problem here with *Bookmark+*, or a way in which it should be improved? If so, please follow up by email and I will take a look: `M-x bmkp-send-bug-report`. Provide as much detail as you can, to help me understand. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

**Drew** has found an answer:

This is an `ido-completing-read+.el` bug.  You will want to report
it to that library's maintainer.  Here is the relevant part of the
source code:

`(when (and def (listp def))
   (setq choices (append def (nreverse (cl-set-difference choices def)))
         def (car def)))`

`(when (and def initial (stringp initial) (not (string= initial "")))
   (setq choices (cons def (remove def choices))
         def nil))`

The variable CHOICES is not declared with `(defvar choices)`, and
the file has local variable `lexical-binding` set to t.  This means
that CHOICES is considered to be a lexically bound variable.  But
is never bound lexically.

Probably the library maintainer just needs to add (defvar choices).
Or else bind `choices`. Or else remove the setting of `lexical-binding'
to t.